# How to properly align divs bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework. I am having a problem with 2 columns not aligning properly - column 3 and 4. Everything else aligns well except for these two. When I use `margin-top` it works for large size devices but when you resize down the divs appear stacked on top of each other. So I thought there has to be a better way of solving this. As you can see the first and second columns are okay. Even if you reduce the screen size, their is no overlapping. Please check out this codepen.

https://codepen.io/danongu/pen/vYOapXE

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container bible">
  <header class="page-header">
    <h2 class="bbltitle">Book Categories</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <article class="panel-group bs-accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">


<div class="col-sm-12 bblcl">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
    <div class="row">
      <span>
        <h4 class="bbtt" style="font-weight:600"> CATEGORY 1 </h4> </span>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<ul> 
<li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 1</a></li><li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


      <div class="col-sm-4">
   <ul> 
<li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse20" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 3</a></li><li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse21" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 4</a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <h4 class="p2p"> CATEGORY 2</h4>
        <ul>
<li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse40" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 5</a></li><li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse41" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 6</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- end inner row -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
     <ul>
<li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse59" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 7</a></li><li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse60" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 8</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
       <h4 class="bbtt" style="font-weight:600"> CATEGORY 3 </h4>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul>
<li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse67" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 9</a></li><li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse68" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 10</a></li>
     </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end inner row -->
  </div>
</div><!-- end outer row -->
</div>
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try `.five-three > .row, .five-two > .row {
    display: flex;
}`

Comment: Did not work as desired. It instead places everything including the headings in their own columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a better way to align your columns, try this:

1. Start by creating a container row (this contains all your category columns)
2. Create one column for each category(**col-md-4**, divides screen into 4 columns ).
3. Inside each category column create 2 rows - one for heading and another for the category list ( book 1, book2..etc)
4. Create 2 columns(**col-md-6** , divides layout into 2 columns) for category list.

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  color:#fff
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color:#561b14 !important
}

.panel-body {
  background:#000 !important;
}
.p2p {
  font-weight:600;
  color:#d6d2cb
}

h4.panel-title {
  color:#fff
}

.panel-default {
  background:#000
}
.bible {
  background:#561B14
}

.bbtt {
  color:#deddd9
}

.bblcl {
  background:#561B14
}
.bbltitle {
  color:#deddd9
}
#accordion li {
  list-style:none;
  padding:5px;
}

#accordion li a { 
color:#deddd9;
  font-size:17px
}
#accordion li a:hover {
  background:#711F14;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  color:#deddd9
}

.five-three h4 {
  padding-left:20px
}

/*Start of CSS OF Chapters */
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} body{margin:0;} a{background:transparent;} a:focus{outline:thin dotted;} a:active,a:hover{outline:0;} *,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;} html{font-size:62.5%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);} body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#333333;background-color:#ffffff;} a{color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;} a:hover,a:focus{color:#2a6496;text-decoration:underline;} a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px;} h4{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:500;line-height:1.1;color:inherit;} h4{margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;} h4{font-size:18px;} .clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table;} .clearfix:after{clear:both;} @-ms-viewport{width:device-width;} format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;} html,body,a{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;-ms-font-smoothing:antialiased;font-smoothing:antialiased;} html{font-size:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);} body{background-color:#f6f4f2;font-size:14px;color:#000;} a{cursor:pointer;} h4{font-size:18px;} h4{color:#676767;font-size:13px;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:15px;margin-top:0;} a:visited{color:#b34b2c;} @media (min-width:768px){h4{font-size:15px;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;line-height:15px;}} a{color:#631e16;text-decoration:none;} a:hover,a:focus{color:#511811;text-decoration:underline;} a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px;} div.bbl-chapters-container{display:none;background-color:black;} @media (max-width:767px){div.bbl-chapters-container{position:relative;height:100%;border-radius:5px;padding-top:45px;}} @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1204px){div.bbl-chapters-container{margin-left:-12px;margin-right:-11px; margin-bottom:-12px}} @media (min-width:1205px){div.bbl-chapters-container{padding:1px 22px 0;margin:-1px 10px 0;border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;}} div.bbl-chapters{} @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1204px){div.bbl-chapters{display:none;margin-bottom:-15px;padding:20px 37px;}}  div.bbl-chapters.open{display:block;} .bbl-chapter-heading{font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:0.15em;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;} .bbl-chapter-heading{display:none;color:#deddd9;} @media (min-width:768px){.bbl-chapter-heading{display:block;margin-top:10px !important}} .bbl-chapters div.bbl-chapter-table{display:none;padding:1px 0 0 1px;} @media (min-width:768px){.bbl-chapters div.bbl-chapter-table{margin:15px 0 0 0;display:inline-block;}} .bbl-chapters.open div.bbl-chapter-table{display:inline-block;} .bbl-chapters div.bbl-chapter{text-align:center;border:1px solid #373738;display:inline-block;margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;} .bbl-chapters div.bbl-chapter:hover{background-color:#902b1f;color:#e8e6e4;} .bbl-chapters div.bbl-chapter a{color:#deddd9;display:block;width:42px;height:42px;line-height:42px;text-decoration:none;font-size:15px;} 

/*
Start of List of Chapters CSS
*/

#bbl ul.books li:hover a{color:#ead3d0;background-color:#902b1f;} 

html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} body{margin:0;} a{background:transparent;} a:focus{outline:thin dotted;} a:active,a:hover{outline:0;} *,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;} html{font-size:62.5%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);} body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.428571429;color:#333333;background-color:#ffffff;} a{color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;} a:hover,a:focus{color:#2a6496;text-decoration:underline;} a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px;} h3{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:500;line-height:1.1;color:inherit;} h3{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px;} h3{font-size:24px;} ul{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:10px;} .clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table;} .clearfix:after{clear:both;} @-ms-viewport{width:device-width;} 

format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;} 

html,body,a{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-font-smoothing:antialiased;-ms-font-smoothing:antialiased;font-smoothing:antialiased;} 
html{font-size:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);} 
body{background-color:#f6f4f2;font-size:14px;color:#000;} 
a{cursor:pointer;} 
h3{font-size:24px;} 
a:visited{color:#b34b2c;} 
a{color:#631e16;text-decoration:none;} 
a:hover,a:focus{color:#511811;text-decoration:underline;} 
a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333;outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px;} 
#bbl-wrapper1{display:none;} 
@media (min-width:768px){#bbl-wrapper1{display:block;}} 
#bbl{display:none;font-size:14px;} 
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1204px){#bbl{margin-left:-165px;padding-left:5px;}} 
@media (min-width:1205px){#bbl{padding-left:5px;}} 
.bbl-column{float:left;padding:0 0 15px 0;margin-left:10px;} 
.bbl-column:first-child{margin-left:0;} 
.bbl-column h3{font-size:14px;color:#ead3d0;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:0.15em;padding-left:20px;} 
.bbl-column:first-child h3{padding-left:10px;} 
.bbl-column ul.books{float:left;width:140px;padding:0;margin:0;line-height:22px;} 
@media (min-width:1024px){.bbl-column ul.books{width:150px;}} 
.bbl-column ul.books.first{float:left;padding-left:10px;border-left:1px solid #711f14;} 
.bbl-column:first-child ul.books.first{padding-left:0;border-left:none;} 
#bbl ul.books li{list-style-type:none;} 
#bbl ul.books li a{display:inline-block;width:90%;padding:0 0 0 10px;border-radius:10px;color:#d6d2cb;text-decoration:none;} 

div.bbl-all-books{padding:0 0 15px 10px;clear:both;} 

.bbl-all-books a{color:#deddd9;}
#bbl-wrapper1 {
  background:#711E13;
  width:1000px
}


/*Start of chapters*/

div.col-sm-7.five-three {
    width: 60% !important;
    }

    div.col-sm-5.five-two {
      width: 40% !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container bible">
    <header class="page-header">
      <h2 class="bbltitle">Book Categories</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
      <article class="panel-group bs-accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <!-- Container -->
        <div class="row bblcl">
          <!-- Category 1 Column -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Category 1 title row -->
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="bbtt text-center" style="font-weight:600"> CATEGORY 1 </h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Category 1 title row -->
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 1</a></li>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse20" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 3</a></li>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse21" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
          </div>
          <!-- Category 1 Column -->

          <!-- Category 2 Column -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Category 2 title row -->
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="p2p text-center" style="font-weight:600"> CATEGORY 2</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Category 2 title row -->
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse40" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 5</a></li>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse41" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 6</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse59" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 7</a></li>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse60" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 8</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
          </div>
          <!-- Category 2 Column -->

          <!-- Category 3 Column -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Category 3 title row -->
            <div class="row">
              <h4 class="bbtt text-center" style="font-weight:600">CATEGORY 3</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Category 3 title row -->
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse67" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 9</a></li>
                  <li><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse68" aria-controls="collapseOne">Book 10</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- 2 column books row -->
          </div>
          <!-- Category 3 Column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Container -->
      </article>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is the fix I have been looking for. Thanks for insightful answer!